# Code to output VTK point data from decomposed domain for Paraview

Tags: visualization, paraview

I am developing a parallel 2D CFD code in C++ using PETSc and would like to use it as an opportunity to learn about VTK/Paraview. Right now, I have each processor output an ASCII file for the portion of the domain that it owns.

Where is a good place to start to learn how to format the data to make a VTK file and view it in Paraview? I have the VTK guide (https://www.kitware.com/products/books/VTKUsersGuide.pdf) but was curious if anyone else has experience with this and could offer some advice on where to start.

The code is based on the finite volume method with a uniform Cartesian mesh. For each cell center, I have information about the pressure, velocity, density, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use VisIt to see vtk files but this may work with Paraview also. Each partition saves its own file which is a standard format and you name them with partition number, e.g.,

```
sol01.vtk
sol02.vtk
sol03.vtk
```

then VisIt can open them together. Make sure the cells in the partitions overlap by adding some ghost cells, otherwise you may have gaps in the visualization.

Comment: Thanks, I'm curious what resource you used to learn how to format the data?